# How to span a textview in layout itself in android?

Tags: android, textview, html

Can I span a textview to make some part bold in the layout itself. I have around 20 xml files. I am not using any activity for them, so I cannot do it programatically. So is there a way to specify it in xml layout itself. I have already tried using  between them but it doesn't works.

```
android:text="Lets look how to make <b> negative sentences <b> in simple present tense."
```

doesn't work.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Check here

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spannable.html

or

https://sites.google.com/site/androidhowto/style-text

or

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/2D-Graphics/UsingSpannabletextandsetstyle.htm

Comment: How is that selected as the correct answer? Forget about the fact that this is not even a legit answer when it comes to SO rules because it's just some links without any explanation, but this doesn't even answer the question. The question is about using Spans in the layout, not in the code.

Answer (score 3):

You can style a textView in xml but I believe it has to be a string resource rather than a hardcoded value like you are doing. Move the string to strings.xml and access it using resource id

```
 android:text="@string/name"
```

Check this [post](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html).

Quoted from the post:

```
Supported HTML elements include:

<b> for bold text.
<i> for italic text.
<u> for underline text.
```